# Check if TCP port connected/established?

Tags: tcp, vbscript

What I want to do is specify a few ports and then check them to see if there is an established connection.  I found the following script and it runs but it only lists 3 ports and I don't understand why.  I verified there are active rules for the ports in question (as well as many others that are not listed in the output below).

```
Set objFirewall = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr")
Set objPolicy = objFirewall.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile

Set colPorts = objPolicy.GloballyOpenPorts

For Each objPort in colPorts
    Wscript.Echo "Port name: " & objPort.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Port number: " & objPort.Port
    Wscript.Echo "Port protocol: " & objPort.Protocol
    Wscript.Echo "Port enabled: " & objPort.Enabled
Next
```

I think I tracked down [the object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365293(v=vs.85).aspx) for `objPort` but I don't even see a status property so I think this is the wrong direction anyway.

Comment: Try http://ss64.com/nt/netstat.html

Comment: I'm familiar with netstat but without doing some major scraping this isn't really a solution.  Unless there is an undocumented feature to only list certain ports?

Comment: The rest won't be open probably due to Windows Firewall

Comment: Wouldn't `telnet.exe <ipaddress> <port>` also do what you want without need for COM objects? Should be able to pull back `StdOut` from `WScript.Shell` to get feedback on whether the port responds or not.

Comment: Note that I don't want to check for an open port, I want to check for a connection.  Would I be able to determine that using telnet?

Comment: What's the difference if you can telnet to a specific ip on a specific port your connected?

Comment: I think one of us is confused :?

Comment: What do you define as *"check for a connection"*?

Comment: if you do `netstat` you will see "ESTABLISHED"

Comment: Sorry you want to see what's connected not check you can connect. Misunderstood, don't think `telnet.exe` will be any use.

Comment: The code you posted is looking at ports not connected sessions *(like you will see with `netstat`)*. They are not mutually exclusive there can be multiple connected sessions to the same port.

Comment: Okay I'm confused, but what I want is to know if there is an active connection to a specific port on my computer.

Comment: A port list is just that a list of ports and their states, in fact that code is specific to the Windows Firewall API, so that's only showing you port state in relation to the Firewalls policy. If you think about Internet Browsers for instance you can have multiple connections to different / same site using the same port *(80, 443 for example)* these would be the equivalent of a connected session. All network traffic works this way.

Comment: Added/updated answer with finalized working vbscript

Comment: Yet another example of how not to write a question on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works great.  However instead of a port I decided to use the `-b` parameter of `netstat` to look for a string in the executable name (in this case "vnc").

```
strCommand = "cmd /C ""netStat -n -b | find ""vnc"""""
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
found = 0
wscript.echo "Waiting for connection..."

Do Until found = 1
    set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec (strCommand)

    strResults = LCase(objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll)

    if len (strResults) > 0 then
        MsgBox "Found VNC connection!"
        found = 1
    else
        WScript.Sleep(5000)
    End if
Loop
```

And here is a bat file that will monitor a specific port. Unfortunately you must run it from a command prompt with elevated privileges.

```
@echo off
SET "strPort=1972"
:LOOP
cls
netStat -n | find ":%strPort%"
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
GOTO LOOP
```

Comment: How does that tell you which port exactly? You've come up with a solution which is different to the requirement in the question.

Comment: I will update though to explain both options for future readers

Comment: I read your answer and because your question doesn't explain why you needed to check whether certain ports had established connections, this answer makes no sense. So it wasn't the port you wanted but the application, that still doesn't tell you which port has a connection to that program although you should be able to get that using the same technique.